# Enviar token en header angular: Como enviar

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando enviar un token en el header con angular pero no logra acceder al api.

Ya estoy obteniendo el token al validar un usuario que esta guardado aquí:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

saveToken(token: String): void {
    localStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN = token;
    this.token = token; // En esta var esta el token
}
```

En ese mismo componente tengo para obtener una lista de usuarios y lo intente de dos maneras:

```
// Forma uno
listarUsuarios() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
    return this.http.get<CUsuarioVO[]>(this.url + "/listas/inactivos", { headers });
  }

// Forma dos
listarUsuarios() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    return this.http.get<CUsuarioVO[]>(this.url + "/listas/inactivos", { headers });
  }
```

El error que me salen en consola es:

> ```
> ERROR  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText:
> "Unknown Error", url:
> "http://192.168.20.21:8080/api/usuarios/listas/inactivos", ok: false,
> …} error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false,
> loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …} headers: HttpHeaders
> {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)} message:
> "Http failure response for
> http://192.168.20.21:8080/api/usuarios/listas/inactivos: 0 Unknown
> Error" name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 0 statusText:
> "Unknown Error" url:
> "http://192.168.20.21:8080/api/usuarios/listas/inactivos"
> __proto__: HttpResponseBase
> ```

Comment: Tu token debe estar malo porque el servidor te da una respuesta vacía: 
https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50859882.html#:~:text=Restsharp%20status%20code%200&text=A%20response%20code%20of%200,known%20as%20a%20FIN%20connection.

Comment: @Pero lo estoy probando en postman con ese mismo token y sirve normal

Comment: pues depende de como se genere el token, si lo haces con oauth2 (oidc) se debe generar para quien lo pide, es decir, si postman pide el token solo postman lo puede usar, aunque esto lo estoy suponiendo, no se como funciona tu token, pero lo que parece estar pasando es que el token no esta siendo aceptado y por eso el servidor te devuelve una respuesta vacía

Comment: El token lo estoy creando con jwt en java spring boot con ``` HS512 ``` y al logearme funciona normal bien pero ya al hacer otra petición con ese token que se creo al logearse no funciona

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas como acceder al `localStorage` correctamente en este link -> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage debes usar la funcion `localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")` para acceder y setItem() para guardar. Por lo que probablemente el error sea que no estés enviando correctamente el token. Prueba logear  `this.token` en la funcion saveToken